# Tensorflow Deep learning network not utilizing GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, gan

I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 755M (PC), which I heard should be at least functional for running deep learning models. But when I train my model (DCGAN) and check the task manager process info (Win 10) I see close to 100% CPU utilization, and very little GPU activity (1-5%). That amount of GPU activity seems to be the constant even if I'm not running a model...so my concern is that I'm not using my graphics card at all, and that I would get better performance if I did.

Furthermore, when I run the following code it indicates that no GPU was found:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import warnings
if not tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    warnings.warn('No GPU found. Please use a GPU to train your neural network.')
else:
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
```

So my questions are the following:

- Is my GPU something that should improve performance vs using the CPU?
- Why isn't tensorflow finding the GPU?
- How can I make Tensorflow utilize the GPU?

I am just beginning to learn about the hardware aspect of ML so any advice and any recommended beginners tutorials for getting basic understanding/intuition would be much appreciated!

Screenshot of component utilization while training a convolutional NN:
[image: Screenshot of component utilization while training a convolutional NN]

Thanks!

Comment: what does running `nvidia-smi` in the terminal return? Have you installed `tensorflow-gpu` instead of just `tensorflow` ? Have you downloaded and installed `cuDNN`     ?

Comment: None of the above :P thanks for the help, I was able to find this based on your reply https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc and will follow it and update here